# android chat application best option

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat, quickblox, sinch

I want to build an android chat application, I'm searching for the API that suits my needs the most.

I was thinking about using a combination of parse and sinch for that but the problem is sinch doesn't support media sharing, so I thought about using just parse to handle the ims and sinch for video and audio calls, my question is will parse allow me to share files such as images, videos etc?

If not, than is Quickblox a better option? The problem with Quickblox is that it doesn't have a rich documentation like Parse and Sinch which is why I'm abstaing away from it.

Comment: Though answer's been accepted I would suggest Layer service. Please check layer.com website. Layer supports Parse as backend. I've used layer with parse and seems pretty good. Also layer has ready made chat controller. More info: atlas.layer.com

Comment: @GiGa I wish that you commented earlier ! atlas.layer.com seems to hold everything I wanted! WIll surely use it in future projects :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Quickblox. But by using Parse.com you can share (save) files Images/Videos/documents .... too up to 10 megabytes each file

check this [link](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#files-the-parsefile)

Comment: Will parse alone work for a real-time chat app? Or should I use something else along with it?

Comment: As of my knowledge .... parse is enough ....If U check in google I saw one open source demo chat app with parse ....